# Making a React Component Scalable on Border Drag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scale

I'm trying to make a React component that is scalable from all directions (N, NE, E, SE, S, SW, W, NW) as seen in this GIF. [image: Scale]

Before I started tackling scaling from all of the directions mentioned above, I wanted to first see if I could implement it from the NE corner, but have been running into problems.

The approach I've taken is to somehow translate the offset of the mouse drag from it's origin to determine a scale factor which can then be applied to the component using the CSS transform property to scale the width and height accordingly.

I'm having issues maintaining the dragging state while the mouse is pressed down onto a button I've situated into the NE corner of the main component which causes the component to resize inconsistently or move in a buggy fashion. I suspect it has something to do with my 'mousemove' and 'mouseup' events, but I'm not quite sure.

Any advice on how to fix this problem/implement this feature? I'd really like to implement this without the use of plugins. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [React Draggable](https://github.com/STRML/react-draggable) the gif you've sent is actually from its parent library.

Comment: thanks, but I’d like to implement this feature without importing third party libraries

Comment: you can just use their source code and change it a bit. It doesn't make sense to implement it without a third party library if you don't want to make major changes to it.